# Calling my website from my phone

Tags: php, apache, phone-call

Is there any way to call my website to receive some data about it?
For example: I connect my phone to my PC and call it from another cell phone and then i press 1 and it will tell me how many users online or something like that?

Comment: I've noticed that when you call Paypal via Skype after confirming your info, it tells you your balance.

Comment: in the world of data-over-gsm, why not just use http/tcp ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no, the long one is yes this is possible but for this functionality you would need a VERY expensive call system to be installed that interfaced with your site.